# How to store data without multiple uploads "if i don't have a file want to upload"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I have a problem when I want to save a new data I don't want to upload file too but I have to code multiple uploads in my public function store. I want to add file when I open edit form and uploaded. what should I do?

I have tried to set validation to set but when I submit error Undefined variable: data.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'employee_sid' => 'required',
        'employee_npk' => 'required',
        'employee_name' => 'required',
        'file_uploads' => 'nullable',
        'file_uploads.*' => 'file|image|mimes:pdf,jpg,jpeg,png',
    ]);

    if($request->file('file_uploads'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('file_uploads') as $file)
        {
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = 'public/file/'.$request->employee_name;
            $file->move($path, $name);
            $data[] = $name;
        }
    }

    $sid = new Sid;
        $sid->employee_sid          = $request->employee_sid;
        $sid->employee_npk          = $request->employee_npk;
        $sid->employee_name         = $request->employee_name;
        $sid->file_uploads          = json_encode($data);
        $sid->save();
```

I expect when I submit that data without the file_uploads it will. but error

```
Undefined variable: data.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the $data variable inside an if, so if the condition is false, the $data variable will be not defined. One possible fix could be:

```
$sid = new Sid;
    $sid->employee_sid = $request->employee_sid;
    $sid->employee_npk = $request->employee_npk;
    $sid->employee_name = $request->employee_name;
    $sid->file_uploads = isset($data)? json_encode($data): null;
    $sid->save();
```

Comment: great! if it help to resolve you problem feel free to [upvote it or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Comment: how about when i want to edit that file ? ex. i create user and i uploads file when i want to edit i just edit the user data without edit the file too. what should i do ? i tried using isset($data)? json_encode($data):null when i update. the files was change to null value in database

Comment: Well, that would be in the update function, right? you can try with `$sid->file_uploads = isset($data)? json_encode($data): $sid->file_uploads;`

Comment: this will replace the field in DB with the new data or will leave it as it was

Comment: thanks sir it works. you're so very helpfull. thank you so much. can i ask other question ? 
how about the field in DB just update. ex. i want to uploads 5 file but when i create i just uploads 2 file and when i want to edit i add 3 file and totals file is 5 in DB. can it do that ?

Comment: Well, that would be a bit more complex and maybe off topic in this question. I suggest you ask another question showing the update function and a title something like "how to update a json field in the database?"